# SQL query not providing results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hoping someone can figure this out.

This sqlfiddle shows the construction on my db/query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2667ba/1/0
And this is the same schema but with a modified query that I can't figure out why it doesn't show any results: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6bb16/1/0

Question being why doesn't the second one show the same results as the first?

I need to reference rows like 'company' and 'newcost' but I also need to reference 'raiseby', which should be the difference in price between the maximum cost of the brand/company and the users maximumbid - as well as which company that is.

I want to echo within a loop to let the user know which company/newcost fell within their parameters as well as which companies just fell short, and display the difference in price (which will say how much the user will need to increase their maximumbid to use that company).

Comment: The SQL Fiddle's are great, but you should edit the question and include the actual queries in the question.  After all, SQL Fiddle could be down, and then your question would make no sense.  You should also explain what the (intended) differences are between the queries, so people don't have to figure that out.

Comment: Don't have two threads on the same topic. It's confusing.

Comment: What is`$current_user->user_login`?

Comment: I'm using Wordpress so that variable, $current_user->user_login is their global variable(s) for login information...so I'm using it to grab the correct rows from only the user that created it

Answer (score 0):

When I removed the `$current_user->user_login` reference in the 2nd jsfiddle and hardcoded 'caseys' as the username, the query appeared to work. Suggests to me just something wrong with that inline replacement at runtime.